# How can I make sure that DELETE SQL statement in Postgres using PHP was successfull?

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there a **function** which would return true of false based on if the DELETE SQL statement succeded or not? For example something like this:

```
<?php
    $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id=123";
    $result = pg_query($sql);

    if **function**($result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
?>
```

Further more, is there maybe a function which returns the number of successfully deleted rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to get number of affected rows in mysql.

Similary for postgres, it will be [pg_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php).

Comment: I'm using postgres, but thanx cause now I've found that basically the same function exists for postgres [pg_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php)

Comment: hmmm, I think I made it pretty clear in the title and the tag ;), thx nevertheless as you made me search and find the function I needed

Answer (score 2):

`if()` is the function ;)

```
if($result)
return true;
else
return false;
```

If you want to know number of successfully deleted rows,loop the if condition

```
$flag=0;
if($result)
{
   $flag++;
}
if($flag==0;)
echo "Nothing is deleted";
else
echo $flag." rows are deleted";
```

Comment: Checking `if ($result)` only tells you whether an ERROR occurs in the `delete` query, not whether rows were deleted. For that you must check with, e.g. `if (pg_affected_rows($result) == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result)
{
  // Delete was successful
}
else
{
  // was not successful
}
```

Comment: Checking `if ($result)` only tells you whether an ERROR occurs in the `delete` query, not whether rows were deleted. For that you must check with, e.g. `if (pg_affected_rows($result) == 0)`.